# How do I perform a SQL update on a list inside one of my table rows?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with parameters as shown below.

```json
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'waccos',
    description: 'Making an operating system in wacc',
    est_duration: 420,
    exp_req: 'any',
    langs: [ 1 ],
    owner: 1,
    members: [ 1, 2 ]
  },
```

I want to use SQL to add a new member into the member list, but I do not know how to. The table is called testprojects. I've tried using

```
(update testprojects 
  set members = members || $1 
where title is $2;', [name, title])
```

but I think that is wrong. Could anyone help me please?

This is the table of members so far.

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'K' },
  { id: 3, name: 'S' },
  { id: 5, name: 'd' },
  { id: 6, name: 'J' },
  { id: 7, name: 'E' },
  { id: 8, name: 'a' }
]
```

Comment: Please tag the DBMS that you are using

Comment: Hi, I am using postgreSQL. Sorry if that doesn't answer your question, I'm very new to all this.

Comment: That's what we need. What is the datatype of column `members`? is that JSON ?

Comment: Yeah, I am using JSON. Members is an Integer list.

Comment: Do you have the complete JSON from your question as a single column value?

Comment: What does this mean sorry?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question. I don't understand if all that is a single JSONB column, or if e.g. `id` or `title` are regular columns and `members` is the JSONB column. And why is the `members` list in the first example an integer array, and in the second example it suddenly has an `id` and `name` key?

Comment: I think it your question would be easier to understand if you can also provide the sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements (together with the mentioned `CREATE TABLE` statement) to make it 100% clear which data goes into which column in which "format"